# pandas : time mask between 'on'/'off'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame as :

```
data=[
{ "event" : "A" , "time" :  "2001-03-31 22:53:22"  , "on/off" :  "on" },
{ "event" : "B" , "time" :  "2001-03-31 22:53:30"  , "on/off" :  "on" },
{ "event" : "C" , "time" :  "2001-04-01 01:32:15"  , "on/off" :  "on" },
{ "event" : "A" , "time" :  "2001-04-01 01:32:18"  , "on/off" : "off" },
{ "event" : "B" , "time" :  "2001-04-01 03:51:32"  , "on/off" : "off" },
{ "event" : "A" , "time" :  "2001-04-01 03:51:33"  , "on/off" :  "on" },
{ "event" : "C" , "time" :  "2001-04-01 04:01:07"  , "on/off" : "off" },
{ "event" : "A" , "time" :  "2001-04-01 04:29:25"  , "on/off" : "off" }]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
```

"on" activate the event and "off" desactivate it 
I want to put 1 for each time  :

- the event is set to on

put 0 for each time :

- the event is set off
- the event isn't activate

I want an output as :

```
                      A     B       C
2001-03-31 22:53:22   1     0       0
2001-03-31 22:53:30   1     1       0
2001-04-01 01:32:15   1     1       1
2001-04-01 01:32:18   0     1       1
2001-04-01 03:51:32   0     0       1
2001-04-01 03:51:33   1     0       1
2001-04-01 04:01:07   1     0       0
2001-04-01 04:29:25   0     0       0
```

I 'm pretty sure there is an elegant method for doing this trick

Answer (score 1):

You can [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `dict` for replace `on` and `off` first.

Then [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) and replace `NaN`s first by `ffill` ([`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) with forward filling), then apply [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) for replace first `NaN`s which are not converted `ffill` and last cast to `int` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html):

```
df['on/off'] = df['on/off'].map({'on':1, 'off':0})

df = df.pivot(index='time', columns='event', values='on/off').ffill().fillna(0).astype(int)
print (df)
event                A  B  C
time                        
2001-03-31 22:53:22  1  0  0
2001-03-31 22:53:30  1  1  0
2001-04-01 01:32:15  1  1  1
2001-04-01 01:32:18  0  1  1
2001-04-01 03:51:32  0  0  1
2001-04-01 03:51:33  1  0  1
2001-04-01 04:01:07  1  0  0
2001-04-01 04:29:25  0  0  0
```

Comment: AWSOME !! Thanks a lot

Comment: @slideWXY - Glad can help!